# Windows 10 taskbar | how to make it thinner when vertical?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have 14" 16:9 notebook and would like my Windows 10 taskbar have on the (left) side. Unfortunately, although I set it to small icons the bar is pretty wide. Do not you know how to make it thinner?

This is how I would like to have it:

[image]

Comment: And how does it look like now?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RbCex.png) is the minimum achievable width on Windows 10. It’s certainly quite ridiculous.

Comment: @DanielB It may be worth editing that screenshot into the question

Answer (score 44):

You could use as tool called "Taskbar Tweaker". After a small search I've heard that it works well with Windows 7, 8 and 8.1. I don't know if it is already implement for Windows 10. According to some beta-tester it should work.

**so try this:**

1. Install 7+ [Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).
2. Right-click on the Tweaker's tray icon, open `advanced options` and set `no_width_limit` to 1.
   [image: Tweaker tray icon]
3. Then use the `no_width_limit` advanced option.
   [image: View of Advanced menu.]

---

- Install 7+ Taskbar Tweaker and run it. You can close the dialog that is displayed.
- Make sure to dock the task-bar to the left edge
- Make sure that it is not locked
- Make sure that you have selected Use small icons option in the task-bar properties

Comment: It's not overkill when it's the only think that works. That program is awesome though.

Comment: Seems to be broken after update to the Windows 10 Creator's update (version 15xxx).

Comment: Seems to have a beta version out fixing the Creator's issue.

Comment: As of October 8, 2017, there's a [stable release version (v5.6)](https://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-for-windows-10-fall-creators-update) that does fix the issue with the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. I just now tested it out on an up-to-date Windows 10 and it works great.

Comment: Still no native solution?

Comment: Where is the "no_width_limit advanced option"? I have installed the latest version and it does not have such options. The photo in the download page also does not show such an option.

Comment: There was an update and I was afraid it stopped working.
But it only resets the settings. This still works as of today!

Answer (score 13):

Right-click an empty area in the taskbar. Uncheck "Lock the taskbar". You should now be able to drag the edge of it to make it thinner (it works when I try it). Lock the taskbar again if you want to avoid accidentally changing it.

Comment: This isn't the problem. Windows 10 simply doesn't let you shrink the vertical taskbar past the length of a long date in the clock widget. Disabling the clock doesn't help.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil I find it doesn't let me shrink the width below the length of the *short* date format.

Comment: I read somewhere that the date is a coincidence - they just put a fixed limit to avoid unclickable buttons on touchscreens. So TaskbarTweaker it is. And I meant AAAA-MM-DD instead of MM/DD when I said long date.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the setting and modify the date/short and long formats to the least characters (count them) you can then make it smaller.

Comment: This doesn't actually work though. The default width is locked and is irrelevant of the date formats.