# Windows 10 taskbar | how to move start button DOWN when vertical?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have ultrawide screen and would like my Windows 10 taskbar have on the (right) side.

Already found a solution to make it thinner (7+ taskbar advanced options), but still looking for ANY working solution to align icons, the "start" button and the start menu itself to the BOTTOM of the task bar. What I want is to flip entire taskbar order.

This is how my taskbar present now:
[my modified taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqWMP.png)

Comment: I am still looking, but I cannot see any native way to change the location of the start button. You cannot if the task bar is horizontal.  Windows 11 is even more limited - no vertical bars at this point 20 months in.

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/q/1057518/152004, https://superuser.com/q/1730385/152004